# Python install from subdirectory without changing folder structure

Tags: python, installation, pip, python-packaging

## Issue I could solve to what I wanted

So I made a whole github repo with a LOT of stuff in it, but then one day I wanted to turn it into a pypi project

So I spend a very long time fiddling with the setup.py and the auto-python-upload.yaml github action and I figure out that for it to work I need it to put all the files in a directory lower

### Example:

Instead of the github repo `baz` looking like this:

```
├── readme.md
├── __init__.py
│── foo
│   ├── bar.py
│   └── __init__.py
```

It needs to be something like:

```
├── readme.md
├── setup.py
│── baz
|   ├── __init__.py
|   │── foo
│   |   ├── bar.py
│   |   └── __init__.py
```

And that's an issue, both for the user having to deal with the project not being shown like it usually is where you can see all the top-level files and also for another situation I also need to solve

But I managed to only fix this because pypi was having a good day and let me upload the entire thing

## The other issue which is similar but I'm still having issues over

Is when you do NOT wish to upload to pypi and just wish to install it from git.

In a separate repo, I figured out with the command `pip install "git+https://github.com/authour/repo#egg=subdir&subdirectory=subdir"` and with a setup.py being put in that folder you can install the package..... but there's a catch.

### Example

I attempted to install the package `foo` with a file directory like this:

```
├── readme.md
├── __init__.py
│── foo
|   ├── setup.py
│   ├── bar.py
|   |── hi
|   |   └── hi.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── other files and folders
```

But when I looked in site-packages the only folder that was there was `hi`, not `foo` which was the folder I wished to install.

So I believe I have to change it to:

```
├── readme.md
├── __init__.py
│── foo
|   ├── setup.py
|   |── foo
│   |   ├── bar.py
|   |   |── hi
|   |   |   └── hi.py
│   |   └── __init__.py
├── other files and folders
```

But that would

1. Be silly to have the code look like `import foo.foo.bar`
2. be annoying if you've referenced it in A LOT of other files, having to change them all
3. be an annoying directory structure to look at

### Please help fix! Would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The 'user' of your package would supposedly be another Python developer, correct? When you use a package, you rarely (if ever) need to access the files and the directory structure of the package. Instead, you approach the package as a namespace. Where the files physically are is only of importance to the package manager and you, the developer of the package. If you follow the standard directions for structuring a package, you'll find that it will work without issue both from PyPI and installed directly from Git. https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: My advice: follow conventional packaging guidelines. I do not think it is worth keeping the current structure in order to prevent "the user having to deal with the project not being shown like it usually is". On the other hand it is worth having a conventional structure so that everyone knows immediately where to find things like in any other Python project around.

Comment: But It's not really a package, it's part of a repo I want to be able to install separately to the rest of the repo if I don't need all the different things in the main one